# SQL first day of week to last day of week or last day of month whichever comes first

Tags: sql

I have a query that uses a SQL expression for the first day of the week (Sunday for my org.) to the last day of the week.

This is the expression I use:

```
Actn - Date Calendar  is between  TIMESTAMPADD(SQL_TSI_DAY,-6, 
(TIMESTAMPADD(SQL_TSI_DAY, DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT_DATE) *-1,CURRENT_DATE))) and 
TIMESTAMPADD(SQL_TSI_DAY, DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT_DATE) *-1,CURRENT_DATE)
```

The expressions works great. I am hoping to enter a clause in here though that says if the end of month becomes before the end of the week I want that to be the last day of the criteria. Is this possible?

Any assistance would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Some of those functions are product specific.)

Comment: I am using Oracel Business Intelligence

Comment: There is no `TIMESTAMPADD()` or `DAYOFWEEK()` function in Oracle. To which backend DBMS system is your BI tool connected to?

Comment: Sorry, I may be confused.  The system is call SMART.  I am not sure if that helps.  Oracle is connected to tables and it queries them.  I do not have a ton of experience with the system.

Comment: I am able to just enter SQL expressions in the system.  I was thinking there may be a way to say if last day of month then unless last day of week.